# Using tiny proxy in perl script - help

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to use a http proxy in my perl script, specifically tinyproxy. I keep getting an error "error in socket creation". can someone point out my errors and how to fix them please, would be very grateful.

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
  my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
  LocalHost => '127.0.0.1',
  LocalPort => '8888',
  Proto => 'http',
  Listen => 5,
  Reuse => 1
```

) or die "ERROR in Socket Creation : $!\n";

```
  $socket->proxy(['http'], 'http://127.0.0.1:8888');
  $mech->get("http://blockexplorer.com/q/getreceivedbyaddress/".$btcaddress);   # Check transactions on bitcoin address
  my $getreceived = $mech->content;
```

Comment: How is this related to Tor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is covered exactly at the [WWW::Mechanize FAQ](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize/FAQ.pod#How_do_I_use_WWW::Mechanize_through_a_proxy_server?) and you need to add *before* connecting a strings like this:

> $mech->no_proxy('localhost');
>
> $mech->proxy('http','http://proxy-ip:proxy-port');

Be warned - it sets *http proxy only*, so if *any* of redirects e.t.c. will use HTTPS, you need to set https proxy too like http one.

Comment: Thank you that did the trick. I am sending requests and often get "too many request" connection refused. Would i be able to install proxychains, say on 127.0.0.1:8888, then use this local address in the solution above in the script. Would it then change to a new proxy when connection is refused?for example sleep (60) then attempt to reconnect

Comment: not by itself - you will need to use either cURL or LWP::UserAgent to make a timeout&state tracking properly. Proxychains are actually not necessery there, but if you will use them - Tor's socks proxy must be **strictly the first one in chain**, but I do recommend you to use Tor alone : it has it's control protocol, it's a very good tool - read the docs ;)